# SVN - Not able to commit files (Can't create directory - no such file or directory)

Tags: svn, commit, smartsvn

I wanted to move our existing repository (from location A) to a new linux server (location B). So, I created a new repository in that server (location B) with the command:-

```
svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs <repository_name>
```

Then I copied the db folder from location A and overwrote that of location B, because I want to keep the previous revisions. I created a system user in location B using the command:-

```
useradd sandeepan
passwd sandeepan
```

I did not specify any permissions for the user on the repository.

After that I took checkout from URL `svn+ssh://<IP>/<path to repository>` and it worked successfully. I am able to update to previous revisions but not able to commit. It says -

`Commit failed - 
Can't create directory 'path/to/repository/db/transactions/1852-1.txn' no such file or directory`

So, I tried to provide access to the repository for that user like this:-

```
groupadd svn_users
usermod -a -G svn_users harry
chgrp -R svn_users /var/backup/hello
```

But still getting the same error. I am using Smart SVN 5.0.4

Thanks,

Sandeepan

**Update**

Even after following Greg's recommendation, I am not able to commit. The error now says `Permission denied`:-

```
Commit failed - Can't create directory 'path/to/repository/db/transactions/1855-1.txn': 
Permission denied
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was because `chmod` was not done!!

I did `chmod -R 770` and it solved the problem.

Comment: this was the reason why the error was happening... so why am I getting negative votes??

Answer (score 6):

When moving a Subversion repository from one machine to another, I would **strongly** recommend that you use [`svnadmin dump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) and [`svnadmin load`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) to copy the repository. There are subtle differences between minor versions of Subversion that make copying the repository database problematic.

Comment: Ok I did'nt know that. Thank you. 

But, even after doing that I am not able to commit. The error now says `Permission denied`:-

`Commit failed - Can't create directory 'path/to/repository/db/transactions/1855-1.txn': Permission denied`

Answer (score 4):

I did a similar move, and have a similar problem. The transactions directory in db did not exist, or I did not copy it. My fix was to manually create the db/transaction directory. I can now commit.

Comment: +1 Just had this issue. My repository was missing both *transactions* and *txn-protorevs* directories. I created these manually and can now commit. How fickle.